# How to make Microsoft.Owin ResponseCookieCollection as interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, cookies, mocking, owin

I need to write Unit Test and I mocked the parameter, but it threw a exception

```
System.NotSupportedException: 
Invalid verify on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.Append("idsvr.account", .account, It.IsAny<CookieOptions>())
```

My production code is:

```
var mockResponseCookieCollection = new Mock<ResponseCookieCollection>(new Moq.Mock<IHeaderDictionary>().Object);
mockResponseCookieCollection.Verify(x => x.Append("idsvr.account", account, It.IsAny<CookieOptions>()));
```

The only solution I can think is use Interface, but I can't change any code in Microsoft.Owin ResponseCookieCollection. Is that anyway can test the method?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that gives more context of what this is testing and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Its difficult to do any help by looking at the provided code, provide more detail / code.